# Plot DataFrame, set X and Y Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I have a Dataframe with multiple columns. It looks like

```
['id', 'timestamp', 'some_number']

[1, 2020-01-01 08:00:00, 88]
[1, 2020-01-01 08:10:00, 12]
[1, 2020-01-01 08:20:00, 55]
[2, 2020-01-01 08:30:00, 13]
[2, 2020-01-01 08:40:00, 100]
....

[15, 2020-01-02 08:00:00, 15]
```

Lets call it 'df_values'.

Now I want to plot it aus lineplot, using Seaborn. I want the ID as Hue (or categories), the timestamp on the x-axis and 'some_value' as my y-axis.

right now, I only see how to set my dataframe as data, but not how to specify it:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df_out)
```

Is there a way to tell seaborn what my x- and y-axis is?

Comment: I thought the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) were pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to structure you command as something like

```
sns.lineplot(data=df_values, x='timestamp', y='some_number', hue='id')
```

Comment: OP called the dataframe `df_values`, also you could add `df_values['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_values['timestamp'])` to your code to ensure that the column is of the right type (this is important in case the times are not linearly spaced). +1